# Can I get the size of a http.NewRequest before I POST?

Tags: json, go, httprequest, gzip

We have an API that accepts JSON. We encourage people to gzip the payload before they POST it because we impose a limit on size. I wanted to see the actual difference in size between raw JSON and gzip'd but I can't seem to reliably and accurately get the size of the http request after it's built.

For the non-compressed version, `MyJSON []byte` is the raw data before I stuff it into the http request like this:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(MyJSON))
```

For the gzip'd version I compress the data into a buffer and then add it to the http request like this:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &buffer)
```

Is it possible to get the size of the http request? And if not, I should be able to get the size of the raw `MyJSON []byte` with `len()`, but I can't seem to get the size of the `bytes.Buffer` for the compressed version.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Len

Answer (score 1):

In a word: No.

This is because the `http.Request` object's body is an `io.Reader`, which could have any size, and the only way to know the size of an `io.Reader` is to read it all, and count.  And in practice, that `io.Reader` is not even consumed until after the data is already in flight.

What this means for your application is that you have two options:

1. You can either read the entire body first, and buffer it (in memory or on disk), count its size, then send it.
2. You can find a way to calculate (or estimate) the size after the request is sent over the wire.

The latter will be more efficient, but means you can't proactively act on the data before sending the request.  If you choose the second approach, you can write a custom `io.Reader` that counts the bytes read, and pass that to your `NewRequest()` call.

---

Also note: The fact that you have your JSON in a byte slice (`[]byte`) is a bit of a code smell. This may be appropriate in some cases, but most of the time, it's more efficient (in terms of memory, and time) to stream your JSON directly to your HTTP request.  Example:

```
var someBigHairyObject = /* Perhaps a struct or map */
r, w := io.Pipe()
go func() {
    err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(someBigHairyObject)
    w.CloseWithError(err)
}()
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://example.com/", r)
```

In this way, the JSON marshaling (and you can include gzip here, too) is done "directly" to the network, without an intermediate buffer, which uses memory, and postpones your request.

Comment: For what it's worth, I only use an encoder for HTTP requests if the document is very large. Otherwise json.Marshal is much simpler and allows to handle encoding errors before starting the request.

Comment: @Flimzy I think you have w and r reversed :)

Answer (score 0):

The question asks how to get the length of a request body where the body is a byte slice or a bytes.Buffer.

As noted in the question, use the builtin [len](https://godoc.org/builtin#len) function to get the length of a byte slice.

Use [Buffer.Len](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer.Len) to get the length of the buffer contents.